# Algorithm for a deck of card

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have this algorithm which is used for a deck with 52 cards, let's say `i=10`:

```
int suit = i / 13;
int cardValue = i % 13;
```

- `suit` is `from 0 to 3` for Hearts, Diamonds, Spades, Clubs
- `cardValue` is `from 0 to 12` for Ace, 2, 3, ... ,Jack, King, Queen

How do I deduce from known `suit` and `cardValue` to get back `i`?

Comment: well if all you want to do is get "i" from some method, using `return i;` would do the trick but you will need to post some more code about where that snippet is located and how it is called.

Comment: Please provide detail information for the sake of getting proper answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but if it's only to obtain "i" from having `suit` and `cardValue`, this would do:

```
int i = suit * 13 + cardValue;
```

Comment: No, it is not correct, take an example, 27. suit would be 27 / 15 (integer division), which would give you a suit of 2. cardValue would be the remainder, which would be 1 (2*13 = 26, 27 - 26 = 1). If you put that into your expression, you would get: 2*13 + (1 - 1), which would give you 26, not the original value. Also, this is really easy to test, you should experiment a bit more, you would've easily seen that your expression would give you the wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

The variable i never changes in this code. If it starts at 10, it will stay as 10. You are only temporarily changing the value for an assignment.